# Finding the limit of an integral using the Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I found the following problem while preparing for some math olympiad in my country.

> Let $c\in (1, +\infty)$ and $f \colon [0, c] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and monotonically increasing function with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Calculate the following limit
> $$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^1 f(x)(f(x+t)-f(x))dx$$
> (the integral is assumed to be a Riemann integral, it is supposed to be solved without Lebesgue integrals)

My approach to solving the problem:

The problem is trivial if we assume that $f$ is differentiable. If we do, then by the mean value theorem, there exists, for each $x \in [0, 1]$ a $c_t \in [x, x+t]$, such that $f(x+t)-f(x)=f'(c_t)*t$. Since $f$ is continuous and $f'$ is bounded, so is $f(x)*f'(c_t)$, for all $t$ near $0$. So our limit becomes $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \int_0^1 f(x)*f(c_t)dx$. By Arzela's theorem for uniformly bounded integrals, we can interchange the limit and the integral and we get $\int_0^1 f(x)*f'(x)dx=0.5*(f(1)^2-f(0)^2)$.

Since every continuous function can be uniformly approximated by polynomials(Stone-Weierstrass theorem), then the set of differentiable functions with bounded derivative are dense in the set of continuous functions with the $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm, so for any continuous function $f_0$, we can find differentiable functions arbitrarily "close" to it.

These observations lead to considering the following function. Let $C$ be the Banach space of continuous functions with the $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm. Let $T \colon C \times (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, T(f)(t) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 f(x)(f(x+t)-f(x))dx$. Consider now, $u \in C$ and $v \in C$ fixed and $t$ an arbitrary positive real number. Then
$$
|T(u)(t)-T(v)(t)| \leq \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 | u(x)u(x+t)-u(x)v(x+t)+u(x)v(x+t)-v(x)v(x+t)+v(x)^2-u(x)^2 |dx \leq \frac{1}{t}\left(\int_0^1|u(x)||u(x+t)-v(x+t)|dx+\int_0^1|u(x)-v(x)||v(x+t)|dx + \int_0^1|u(x)-v(x)||u(x)+v(x)|dx\right) \\ \leq \frac{1}{t} \left(\|u\|_{\infty}\|u-v\|_{\infty}+\|u-v\|_{\infty}\|v\|_{\infty} + \|u-v\|_{\infty}\|u+v\|_{\infty}\right) \leq \frac{1}{t} \left( \|u-v\|_{\infty} \left( \|u\|_{\infty}+\|v\|_{\infty} + \|u+v\|_{\infty} \right) \right) \leq \frac{1}{t} \left( 2\|u-v\|_{\infty} \left( \|u-v\|_{\infty}+2\|v\|_{\infty}\right) \right)
$$

Therefore $T$ is continuous in $f$ uniformly in $t$. Because of $T(f)(t)$ converges uniformly to some function $g(t)$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \lim_{f \to f_0} T(f)(t) =\lim_{f \to f_0} \lim_{t \to 0} T(f)(t) 
$$

To justify the interchange of limits, let's denote $g(t)\colon=\lim_{f \ to f_0} T(f)(t)$, $h(f)= \lim_{t \to 0} T(f)(t)$ and $l=\lim_{f \to f_0} \lim_{t \to 0} T(f)(t)$. Now let $a$ be a function such that $\|a-f_0\|<\delta$. We can see that
$$
|g(t)-l| \leq |g(t)-T(a)(t)+T(a)(t)-h(a)+h(a)-l| \leq |g(t)-T(a)(t)| + |T(a)(t)-h(a)| + |h(a)-l|
$$
And each term can be made arbitrarily small.

Since the differentiable functions are dense in $C$, we can assume WLOG that $f$ is differentiable in the limits above. The question in the problem is equivalent to $\lim_{t \to 0} \lim_{f \to f_0} T(f)(t)$. And by interchanging limits, the result is trivial.

Is my proof correct? To me it seems like it is, but I never used the monotonicity of $f$?

Comment: The function $f$ may be not continuous so the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is not useful. I have impression that the problem is associated with the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int\limits_0^1f\,df$ and the formula of integration by parts $$\int\limits_0^1g\,df\\ =g(1)f(1)-g(0)f(0)-\int\limits_0^1f\,dg$$ when $g=f$ we get $\int\limits_0^1f\,df={1\over 2}[f(1)^2-f(0)^2].$

Comment: If $f$ is not right continuous at $1$ the outcome is not equal ${1\over 2}.$ For example let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0\le x\le 1\\
x+4 & x>1
\end{cases}$$
Then $${1\over t}\int\limits_0^1f(x)[f(x+t)-f(x)]\,dx\\
\ge {1\over t}\int\limits_{1-t/2}^1f(x)[f(x+t)-f(x)]\,dx\\ \ge {1\over t}\int\limits_{1-t/2}^1 4x\,dx\ge 2$$

Comment: I forgot to add that $f$ is continuous, my bad